# Azure AD and .NET Core MVC - multiple authentication providers

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an application which will be used by 2, possibly more, organisations.

Both organisations want their staff to login via their Azure AD accounts, as well as their external contractors.

I'm confused on how best to implement this... is it possible for one application to authenticate against 2 separate Azure AD tenants? I guess there would be 2 login buttons, one for org x and one for org y.

As for their external contractors, would B2C be the way for them to control access to their contractors?

I guess the other option is to host the web app twice - one for each organisation??

Comment: As far as I know, Azure AD provide multiple-tenants apps.I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps) to know what is multiple-tenants apps. Besides, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) to know how to convert an existing app to be multi-tenant.

Comment: Thanks @MG123 and Please follow this document and it will help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant